# Opening .csv on online Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a .csv file, I uploaded it into Jupyter Notebook online.

[image]

I want to open it using pandas with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('demo/big.csv')
```

Outputs an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/demo/big.csv' does not exist: b'/demo/big.csv'
```

Comment: try `open('demo\\big.csv')`

Comment: Try writing `!ls` or `!dir` in a cell to find out where the file is.

Comment: It worked with df = pd.read_csv(open('big.csv')). Please write it as an answer so I can close the post.

Comment: Done. ---------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
df = pd.read_csv(open('big.csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('big.csv')
```

Comment: That should work as long the notebook and the csv are in the same folder. Otherwise you need to use `..` to go down in the folders `pd.read_csv('..\big.csv')`